# Danger of not properly encoding html characters

Tags: html, character-encoding, chars

Are there any dangers of not properly encoding html chars such as `£` and `&` ?

I know if you want to write :

> It was nice & cost £1

your html would be :

`It was nice &amp; cost &pound;1`

But is there any danger if your html was :

`It was nice & cost £1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode the `&` as it has meaning in HTML and some parsers may not cope with it, even if most modern browsers can infer what you meant to do.

The `£` however doesn't **have** to be encoded unless for some reason you have to encode your page as ASCII or if there's a risk of getting your character sets confused (e.g. UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1).